# How to split column into separate columns based on same ID?

Tags: sql-server, pivot, common-table-expression

I have a dataset that looks like this and is called ALL_SOURCES_MERGE

| OVID | ID_VALUE | NAME | SOURCE | LOCATION | MLP_ID | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 686B93E0-A047-4BF5-B6B1-A775C20390EF | ABC | PETE | SOURCE_1 | USA | 1X | ZZ |
| 7374F6A8-352D-44CF-8FA2-EBCB205EE18B | DEF | ADAM | SOURCE_2 | ZAF | 2X | SS |
| 686B93E0-A047-4BF5-B6B1-A775C20390EF | GHI | PETE | SOURCE_3 | ZAF | 3X | QQ |
| 27C063A0-E8DD-4808-8CC5-12108C380DD4 | JKL | JAKE | SOURCE_1 | RUS | 4X | EE |
| 7374F6A8-352D-44CF-8FA2-EBCB205EE18B | MNO | LEAH | SOURCE_1 | JAP | 5X | RR |
| 686B93E0-A047-4BF5-B6B1-A775C20390EF | ABC | MEAH | SOURCE_4 | CHN | 6X | GG |

I want to see per ID where the `[ID_VALUE]` matches/differs from the `[ID_VALUE]`
& where the `[NAME]` matches/differs from the `[NAME]`

Essentially I want to see all the data per ID - I want to split the columns.
Something in the line of:

| OVID | SOURCE_1_ID | SOURCE_2_ID | SOURCE_3_ID | SOURCE_4_ID | SOURCE_1_NAME | SOURCE_2_NAME | SOURCE_3_NAME | SOURCE_4_NAME | SOURCE_1_LOCATION | SOURCE_2_LOCATION | SOURCE_3_LOCATION | SOURCE_4_LOCATION | SOURCE_1_MLP_ID | SOURCE_2_MLP_ID | SOURCE_3_MLP_ID | SOURCE_4_MLP_ID | SOURCE_1_TYPE | SOURCE_2_TYPE | SOURCE_3_TYPE | SOURCE_4_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 686B93E0-A047-4BF5-B6B1-A775C20390EF | ABC | NULL | GHI | ABC | PETE | NULL | PETE | MEAH | USA | NULL | ZAF | CHN | 1X | NULL | 3X | 6X | ZZ | NULL | QQ | GG |
| 7374F6A8-352D-44CF-8FA2-EBCB205EE18B | MNO | DEF | NULL | NULL | LEAH | ADAM | NULL | NULL | JAP | ZAF | NULL | NULL | 5X | 2X | NULL | NULL | RR | SS | NULL | NULL |
| 27C063A0-E8DD-4808-8CC5-12108C380DD4 | ABC | NULL | NULL | NULL | JAKE | NULL | NULL | NULL | RUS | NULL | NULL | NULL | 4X | NULL | NULL | NULL | EE | NULL | NULL | NULL |

In summary, what I want to check is where one `ID` has different names AND/OR different `ID_VALUES`.
I think I will be able to compare if I split the columns `ID_VALUES` and `NAME` into separate columns.

I have tried pivoting the ID_VALUE AND NAME columns but the result is a table that has a structure like the desired outcome but all entries are NULL in the SOURCE_#*ID and SOURCE*#_NAME columns.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: That's kind of the _opposite_ of splitting (which usually means taking a single value and extrapolating it across rows), and certainly not merge. The concept you're looking for is a PIVOT, and there are many questions about it here - the answer you need will depend on both the version of SQL Server you're using and whether or not you have a finite set of known columns to pull out (e.g. could an ID have more than two sources, or two names, or two locations, etc). Yitzhak is absolutely right, instead of just showing column headers, show the actual data you expect, along with any edge cases.

Comment: For each ID you would need a different number of `name` and `id_value` columns as I'm assuming there are more than just 2 for each one, right? How would that work as a result set where one row would need maybe 4 name columns and the next might only need 1? To me, instead of separate columns, a string_agg() with distinct values for each column grouped by `id` might be more appropriate.

Comment: I have updated my question to be more clear.